# Store arbitrary binary data on a system accepting only valid UTF8

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I have arbitrary binary data. I need to store it in a system that expects valid UTF8. It will never be interpreted as text, I just need to put it in there and be able to retrieve it and reconstitute my binary data.

Obviously base64 would work, but I can't have that much inflation.

How can I easily achieve this in python 2.7?

Comment: Question at the margin: Python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: [What do you intend to do with these bytes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux It's 2.7

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm storing them, they will be read by a package that I have to interface with that will interpret them as utf-8, regardless of BOM or anything.

Comment: _"interpret them as utf-8"_ But you said your raw data may contain _"invalid in UTF-8"_. How your "package" will deal with that ? Or do you simply want _discard_ any "invalid UTF8" values ? You probably know what you are doing, but if I were you, I would nevertheless take time to think if I will not introduce  [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in my system...

Comment: Is this an accurate summary of what you need?  "I have arbitrary binary data. I need to store it in a system that expects valid UTF8.  It will never be interpreted as text, I just need to put it in there and be able to retrieve it and reconstitute my binary data."

Comment: @NedBatchelder Yes. Exactly.

Comment: @N.McA. I took the liberty to edit your question by merging the comment of Ned Batchelder. Please review that change.

Comment: You could take a look at the yEnc encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YEnc or come up with an own encoding scheme that makes sure that UTF8 is not violated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description. Basically you can use any ASCII value from 0 to 127 without breaking the encoding. For the byte values above 127 you need to introduce a code point. You will only need the 11 bit code point for encoding the remaining values (see Wikipedia table).

Comment: @N.McA. Next question: why can't you have the 33% inflation that base64 gives you?

Comment: @NobuGames: You need to take into account that control characters in the ASCII range could be interpreted too; that's why it is still safest to stick to the printable range; otherwise you could use a Base128-style encoding to pack 7 data bytes into 8 7-bit characters.

Comment: @NobuGames: extending into multi-byte UTF8 codepoints is not worth your while, as the average number of bits per byte *drops* as you use more UTF-8-valid bytes.

Comment: @NedBatchelder The application is for storing binary files on paper. 33% expansion is a big deal on a sheet of A4 (not my own stupid idea btw, I'm just implementing it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll *have* to express your data using *just* ASCII characters. Using Base64 is the most efficient method (available in the Python standard library) to do this, in terms of making binary data fit in printable text that is also UTF-8 safe. Sure, it requires 33% more space to express the same data, but other methods take *more* additional space.

You can combine this with *compression* to limit how much space this is going to take, but make the compression optional (mark the data) and only actually use it if the data is going to be smaller.

```
import zlib
import base64

def pack_utf8_safe(data):
    is_compressed = False
    compressed = zlib.compress(data)
    if len(compressed) < (len(data) - 1):
        data = compressed
        is_compressed = True
    base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
    if is_compressed:
        base64_encoded = '.' + base64_encoded
    return base64_encoded

def unpack_utf8_safe(base64_encoded):
    decompress = False
    if base64_encoded.startswith('.'):
        base64_encoded = base64_encoded[1:]
        decompress = True
    data = base64.b64decode(base64_encoded)
    if decompress:
        data = zlib.decompress(data)
    return data
```

The `'.'` character is not part of the Base64 alphabet, so I used it here to mark compressed data.

You could further shave of the 1 or 2 `=` padding characters from the end of the Base64 encoded data; these can then be re-added when decoding (add `'=' * (-len(encoded) * 4)` to the end), but I'm not sure that's worth the bother.

You can achieve further savings by switching to the [Base85 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85), a 4-to-5 ratio ASCII-safe encoding for binary data, so a 20% overhead. For Python 2.7 this is only available in an external library (Python 3.4 [added it to the `base64` library](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#base64)). You can use [`python-mom` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mom) in 2.7:

```
from mom.codec import base85
```

and replace all `base64.b64encode()` and `base64.b64decode()` calls with `base85.b85encode()` and `base85.b85decode()` calls instead.

If you are 100% certain nothing along the path is going to treat your data as *text* (possibly altering line separators, or interpret and alter other control codes), you could also use the Base128 encoding, reducing the overhead to a 14.3% increase (8 characters for every 7 bytes). I cannot, however, recommend a pip-installable Python module for you; there is a [GitHub hosted module](https://github.com/ysangkok/python-binary-in-utf8/blob/master/base128.py) but I have not tested it.

Comment: actually, base128 would be more efficient whilst fulfilling the requirement of using only ASCII characters. there are base128 libraries available (e.g. https://www.npmjs.org/package/base128)

Comment: @isedev: you'd have to guarantee that control characters are never going to be interpreted anywhere during the lifetime of the encoded data, though.

Comment: @isedev: for example, if this data is ever written to disk on a Windows system where the file is opened in text mode (quite common) then all `\x0a` codepoints (e.g. newlines) will be expanded to CRLF separators (so `\x0d\x0a`), disastrous for binary data.

Comment: @isedev The linked package is also not in python.

Comment: @N.McA.: we can find you a base128 implementation in Python, that's not the problem. The problem is that in textual data control characters carry meaning and can end up being altered or breaking systems you may not even be aware of are part of the chain.

Comment: oops, got the link wrong... but as Martjin says, base128 is probably not a good idea in most cases.

Comment: here's one in python: https://github.com/ysangkok/python-binary-in-utf8/blob/master/base128.py

Comment: @N.McA.: I added a recommendation for Base85 too; this is still ASCII-safe but reduces the overhead to 20% rather than 33%. The downside is that you need to install an external package.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. Base128 will be fine, as the string is not going to be stored on anything that will alter it (Really, it won't - it's going on paper). Thanks all for the help. :)

Comment: Again, this begs the question how you distinguish between line feed, vertical tab, and carriage return if you really are going to use paper as your medium. Of course, if you have the possibility to use a font which has clearly distinguishable symbols for these normally nonprinting control characters, all is well.

Comment: Aha, not as characters - encoded as a QR code. I know QR's are meant to be able to store generic binary data, but the implementation I'm tied to can't - it assumes that 'binary' means 'utf-8'

Comment: @N.McA.: I'd do some testing with a binary string with all 255 possible byte values and round-trip that. Don't make assumptions about the QR generating library nor the QR reader not translating control codes here.

Comment: (256 values I presume :-)

Comment: @tripleee: ick, yes, 256. Off-by-one error in my subroutines.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode your bytes as 8859-1 data, which will always produce a valid Unicode string.  Then you can encode it to UTF8:

```
utf8_data = my_bytes.decode('iso8859-1').encode('utf8')
```

On average, half your data will be in the 0-127 range, which is one byte in UTF8, and half your data will be in the 128-255 range, which is two bytes in UTF8, so your result will be 50% larger than your input data.

If there is any structure to your data at all, then zlib compressing it as Martijn suggests, might reduce the size.

Comment: Base64 encoding only expands the data by 33%; I had considered using latin-1 but base64 simply beats the odds here.

Comment: Hmm, I overlooked that! Base64 is better than UTF8. :(

Comment: Plus Latin-1 does not have code points 128-159, and ASCII codes 0-31 (or 32 even) do not conventionally have standard glyphs.

Comment: @tripleee: printability is not at issue here; the OP is putting this in a QR code.

Answer (score 0):

If your application really requires you to be able to represent 256 different byte values in a graphically distinguishable form, all you actually need is 256 Unicode code points. Problem solved.

ASCII codes 33-127 are a no-brainer, Unicode code points 160-255 are also good candidates for representing themselves but you might want to exclude a few which are hard to distinguish (if you want OCR or humans to handle them reliably, áåä etc might be too similar). Pick the rest from the set of code points which can be represented in two bytes -- quite a large set, but again, many of them are graphically indistinguishable from other glyphs in most renderings.

This scheme does not attempt any form of compression. I imagine you'd get better results by compressing your data prior to encoding it if that's an issue.

Comment: Oops, this is pretty similar to Ned's answer, but it addresses some issues with his proposal.